# Rails has_many through query, with two references aka using through table attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking for a way to query a model based on children in a has_many through association.

I have these models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :squads, through: :members
end

class Squad < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :squad
end
```

I'm basically using the Member class to provide a relationship between User and Squad, so it can hold membership information such as role, position, number, .etc

The goal is to have the `Member` model store `User` membership info as it relates to any `Squad`. A User can be an owner of one squad, be a member of another, and not be a member of yet another squad.

I am trying to display a Join link in my index.html.erb for all User's that do not have any member connection to a squad.

Currently, working with

```
<% @squads.each do |squad| %>
  <td><%= squad.name %></td>
  <% if Squad.includes(:members).where( 'members.user_id' => params[:users]).exists? %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Join', join_squad_path(:id => squad) %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

with the primary line being

`<% if Squad.includes(:members).where( 'members.user_id' => params[:users]).exists? %>`

also tried stuff such as

- `User.includes(:squads, :members).where('squads.id = ? AND members.users = ?', squad, current_user)`
- `u = squad.users.includes(:member).where('member.user = ?', current_user)`
- `Member.where.not("squad = #{squad.id}").find(user: current_user.id)`

I have an instance variable for each |squad| and have current_user.id available for the logged in user (using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise))

Referencing [Ruby on Rails Guide: Association Basics - the has many through association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to show the button if the logged user is not a member of each squad? If so...

`has_many` association provides the method `other_ids` which returns an array of the associated objects' ids (in your case `squad.user_ids`). So you can check if the current user's id is in that array:

```rb
<% @squads.each do |squad| %>
  <td><%= squad.name %></td>
  <% unless squad.user_ids.include?(current_user.id) %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Join', join_squad_path(id: squad) %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
User.includes(:members).where(members: { id: nil }).or(User.includes(:members).where.not(members: { squad_id: squad.id }))
```

**Explanation:**

```
User.includes(:members).where(members: { id: nil })
```

To query users that have no member record (belong to no squad)

```
User.includes(:members).where.not(members: { squad_id: squad.id })
```

To query users that do have member record but not member of the target squad.